# how can i remove word from strings using def and for function?

Tags: python

Snippet of code:

```
def find_min(string):
    a = 'b1!!Ze44B&cC3#dd$$8'
    d=[]
    min_=10000
    for i in a:
        d.append(ord(i))
        for y in d:
            if min_>y:
                min_=y
                string=chr(min_)
                a=string
    return a 
a='b1!!Ze44B&cC3#dd$$8'
print(find_min(a))
    #output=!
def delete_element(string,element):
    t=''
    b=find_min(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        b = find_min(a)
        a=a.replace(a[i],'',i)
        a = delete_element(a,b)
        t= b+ t
        print(a)
        print(t)
        print()              
t=''
b=''
string=''
delete_element(a,b)
```

#output
'b1!Ze44B&cC3#dd$$8'
!
'b1Ze44B&cC3#dd$$8'
!!
'b1Ze44B&cC3dd$$8'
#!!

What should I do to finish the code? I would like the def function to return the extracted element (def min) as well as the string indicating which element was removed.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Please provide an example of input and output. Additionally, your code is not executable. Could you please make the necessary changes as well? Or, at the very least, delete any unnecessary items, such as an empty print.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do with *delete_element* but I can tell you that *find_min* can be replaced with *sorted(string)[0]*

Comment: thanks for comments! However is there a way to repeat the order 'find_min' in the second def? I think I would be able to solve if I know how to repeat the order...

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat the order"? Please give more examples of the input/output

Comment: the upper one is the output...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly then this should work for you:

```
def delete_element(string):
  return string.replace(sorted(string)[0], '')

print(delete_element('b1!!Ze44B&cC3#dd$$8'))
```

...will output b1Ze44B&cC3#dd$$8

Comment: Thanks! However, is there a way to repeat the order I mentioned on the first def 'find_min(a)' on the second def by using "for"?